# Data access issue in Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms

The code is:
Commodity:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to insert an Commodity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commodity">commodity's information</param>
    /// <returns>void</returns>
    public bool Add(Models.CommodityInfo commodity)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(commodity.Sp_itemnum) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(commodity.Sp_name))
            return false;
        else
            return dal.Insert(commodity);
    }
    ///interface is omitted
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to insert an Commodity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commodity">commodity's information</param>
    /// <returns>Whether the operation is successful</returns>
    public bool Insert(CommodityInfo commodity)
    {
        StringBuilder strSQL = new StringBuilder(SQL_INSERT_COMMODITY);

        // Get each commands parameter arrays
        SqlParameter[] Parms = GetParameters();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        // Set up the parameters
        Parms[0].Value = commodity.Sp_itemnum;
        Parms[1].Value = commodity.Sp_name;
        Parms[2].Value = commodity.Sp_spec;
        Parms[3].Value = commodity.Sp_classify;
        Parms[4].Value = commodity.Sp_brand;
        Parms[5].Value = commodity.Sp_purcprice;
        Parms[6].Value = commodity.Sp_saleprice;
        Parms[7].Value = commodity.Sp_origin;
        Parms[8].Value = commodity.Sp_pack;
        Parms[9].Value = commodity.Sp_note;
        foreach (SqlParameter parm in Parms)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);

        // Create the connection to the database
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SqlHelper.connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strSQL.ToString();

            int r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //Clear the parameters
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            return Convert.ToBoolean(r);
        }
    }
```

Storage:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to add a commodity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="spName">name of commodity of add</param>
    /// <returns>Whether the operation is successful</returns>
    public bool addCommodity(string spName)
    {
        bool r = true;

        BLL.WareHouseManager bwm = new WareHouseManager();
        BLL.CommodityManager bcm = new CommodityManager();
        Models.StorageInfo msi = new Models.StorageInfo();
        msi.Sp_id = bcm.GetCommodityIdbyName(spName);
        msi.Cc_num = 0;

        IList < int> ckIds = bwm.GetAllCkId();
        for(int i = 0; i < ckIds.Count; ++i)
        {
            msi.Ck_id = ckIds[i];
            if (!dal.Insert(msi))
                r = false;
        }
        return r;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to Insert a storageinfo
    /// </summary>
    public bool Insert(Models.StorageInfo msi)
    {
        StringBuilder strSQL = new StringBuilder(SQL_INSERT_RECORD);

        // Get each commands parameter arrays
        SqlParameter[] parms = GetUpdateParameters();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        // Set up the parameters
        parms[0].Value = msi.Ck_id;
        parms[1].Value = msi.Sp_id;
        parms[2].Value = msi.Cc_num;

        foreach (SqlParameter parm in parms)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);

        // Create the connection to the database
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SqlHelper.connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strSQL.ToString();

            int r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //Clear the parameters
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            return Convert.ToBoolean(r);
        }
    }
```

The question is:
Database table structure:
[Table of commodity and storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuxUN.png)

The error place:

```
            if(addCommodity.Add(addCommodityInfo))//add a commodity into table of commodity
        {
            if (bsm.addCommodity(addCommodityInfo.Sp_name))//set the number of stores in every warehouse to 0---------》error point（In debug，the error is when its SQL was executing）
            {
                MessageBox.Show("operation success", "Tips", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                table_SPTableAdapter.Fill(jcxWorksDataSet.Table_SP);
            }
            else
            {
                addCommodity.Delete(addCommodityInfo.Sp_name);
            }
        }
```

The VS2015 given information “Foreign key conflict”,but it’s executed successfully in sql server Managerment studio

Others：I am Chinese. If you know chinese,you can look this
[enter link description here](http://bbs.csdn.net/topics/392169727?page=1#post-402359446)

Comment: Please can you outline what the actual error is..

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The question has been modify.

Answer (score 0):

Just check in case you are trying to insert some value to `Table_CC.sp_id` column which is not there in `Table_SP.sp_id`

Comment: Thanks for your reply very much. This is the key of my question.Before I was trying to insert value to Table_CC.sp_id,I just insert the value needed to Table_SP.sp_id.  I used the data gotten in debug, it’s executed successfully in sql server Managerment studio

Comment: where is `dbo.Table_CK`. I found it in yourerror screenshot above.@wuyi

Comment: I'm sorry.I put a wrong image because of my carelessness.The error in the screenshot is another error which is in similar code structure.The all is commodity-storage-warehouse.The dbo.Table_CK is table of warehouse.